# Unable to install rabbitmq due to not meeting dependencies: libssl

Tags: 18.04, rabbitmq, erlang

I want to install rabbitmq on my Ubuntu 18.04. I have been following the official [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html). However, my installation is not completed as I am getting stuck on the step: `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing` as I face an error: unmet dependencies.

I tried installing libssl and then erlang-crypto, didn't work. I also installed `aptitude` using which I tried installing `erlang-crypto`, it also didn't install any package.

The command that I am running is:

```
sudo apt-get install -y erlang-base \
                        erlang-asn1 erlang-crypto erlang-eldap erlang-ftp erlang-inets \
                        erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-public-key \
                        erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssl \
                        erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tftp erlang-tools erlang-xmerl
```

I get a failure message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 erlang-crypto : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The `libssl` package isn't available and I have successfully installed `libssl-dev`.

I expect to completely install RabbitMQ and it runs successfully.

Comment: The link is tl;dr. Please edit your question to describe what you have actually done.

Comment: @fkraiem
Hi! Thank you for your response, apologies if the question isn't clear.
As you can see, I have written the commands that I ran and the error messages following them. I am sorry but I did not understand what else should be included. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Looks like you have made a classic new-user mistake: Trying to run bleeding-edge software on an older release of Ubuntu. In Debian-based Linux systems like Ubuntu, applications and the OS are very tightly integrated, and share many libraries. Each library can have only one version installed, and it needs to be compatible with *everything* on the system. This means that a 2018-era OS will run 2018-era software. When you try to run newer software, you create the "impossible situation" (otherwise known as a *version conflict*). Either use an older release of RabbitMQ or a newer release of Ubuntu.